# Endless Marquee effect with CSS/jQuery or AngularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I'm using angularjs to display a list of names and I need to scroll it automatically top to bottom infinitely (endless). I used "marquee" tag for this( I know it is outdated ) but it matches with the requirement. Only issue is once it goes up, it shows a big gap (blank screen) until the next round start showing.

my current code is this:

```
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="up" width="100%" scrollamount = "2">
                    <div class="fz-row" ng-repeat="sel in scroll_array">
                        <div class="fz-row-wrap"> 
                           <div class="fz-horse-number" ng-class="{'fav': (sel.fav == 'Y')}">{{sel.sel_num}}</div>
                           <div class="fz-horse-jercy"><img ng-src="{{sel.jersey}}"></div>
                           <div class="fz-horse-name" ng-class="{'fav': (sel.fav == 'Y')}">{{sel.sel_name | uppercase}}</div>
                           <div class="fz-horse-seconday-odds">{{sel.odds}}</div>
                           <div class="fz-horse-primary-odds">
                               <div class="fz-yellow-tag" ng-class="{'fav': (sel.fav == 'Y')}"><span>{{sel.lastOdd}}</span></div>
                           </div>
                           <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </marquee>
```

I can't use additional libraries instead of angularjs and jquery. Is it possible to handle this case with CSS ? or javascript ? If there is any very light-weight plugin, I can use it as it won't increase the '.war' file size that much when deploying it remotely.